# Unremovable folder on Desktop

Tags: windows-xp

I am unable to remove a folder on my desktop named `http`.

When I try to drag and drop something into that folder, another folder is created with a same name.

Moreover, when I intend cut or copy something from desktop to any of my drives, "My Computer" or "My Documents" doesn't open. Normally they open.

Answer (score 1):

Use unlocker

http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/

In addition to clicking "Unlock All" you can select delete in the Action dropdown

Comment: Unlocker is Not working...

Comment: My second choice would be to boot using a live CD.  I use Puppy Linux because it boots up fast and has links to all the partitions on its desktop.  Then you can navigate to the windows desktop folder and delete from there.  I usually only go this route with viruses, because with permission or locked file issues unlocker does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a permissions issue. If you really want that folder gone, you can open up a command line (Win+R, type `cmd.exe`). Navigate to your desktop `cd /path/to/desktop/`. Then try `deltree http`

If that doesn't work try and see the permissions of the folder, then that will tell you what the issue might be.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, boot from a Linux Live CD/DVD/USB and remove the file from the CLI

Comment: And if THAT doesn't work, boot from a Linux Live CD and INSTALL TO DISK. :)

Comment: When I try to see its permission-status by right-clicking and selecting Properties, nothing is shown.

Comment: I don't think windows will show you permissions on folders from the right-click/properties menu. I would try the CLI way.